# How to execute Laravel (email) jobs on live server

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, jobs

Good day all. I just finished building a laravel app. In the app, I made use of **Jobs, Mails and Queue (for the first time)**. On my server, I can run
`php artisan queue:work` to carry out the job (like sending bulk mails to subscribers). This is working fine. The problem now is that I want to put the website live now, and I seem lost on how to make this work on a live server, since I won't always be there to type the `php artisan queue:work` command (that's even if it's possible). Please, how do I go about this?

My .env settings is shown below

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure cron to execute artisan commands. Edit your cron and add this line (edit path):

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

To ensure that everything is correctly configured, I suggest that you take a time and [read the docs about Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling)

EDIT #1
If you want to execute only the queue:work, add this line to yor cron (edit path):

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan queue:work >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I hope it helped in the finalization of the project implementation.